# How to allow download of files on a HTML server?

Tags: html, iis-8

I have setup a HTML Server to run on Windows Server 2012. I have added few virtual directories and some files.

I am trying to download a file firmware.dob. But when I click on the file the browser reports "File not found"

```
    404 - File or directory not found.
```

As an admin, how do i enable users/make the browser to download file rather that try to open it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be done by PHP. If you have just HTML i don't think this can be solved. In PHP you could set a Header. Perhaps you can use your admin tools of your server to set some properties of the file you're talking about. maybe the server gives you the option to force download prompts.

If you can only use HTML you might consider using a flash plugin for this. But this would only work on desktops, not on mobile phones. You could look into this: [Creating download prompt using purely javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548102/creating-download-prompt-using-purely-javascript)