# Prompting browser to download file retrieved from http get through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, download

I have a form that does a http-get which returns a file. If I simply use the in-built get from form the browser attempts to download the file, which is what I want. However, I want to do the http-get through jQuery so that I can display a loading bar that terminates when the get has finished its request. (Request takes ~20 seconds)

I do the request like this:

```
 $('#dagens').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    nanoBar.go(50);
    console.log("NProgressShouldHaveStarted")

    $.get( $(this).attr('action'), function( data ) {
        $( ".result" ).html( data );
            console.log( "Loadwasperformed.");
            nanoBar.go(100);
    });
  });
```

I gather that the file resides in 'data', but how can I pass this to the browser so that it prompts the user to download it?

Comment: is data the files content or url?

Comment: The file's content. If I do                     $('#view').html(data); the file content is dumped to the browser as text. (It's a csv-file)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548102/creating-download-prompt-using-purely-javascript

Comment: I see, but content-disposition and contentType is set server side and I don't really WANT to store it as a variable, I just want the jQuery-get to do the same as if I just do    <form action="<%= uri("/last-ned-dagens") %>" id="dagens" >
        <button type="submit" id="js-last-ned-button" >Last ned dagens uttrekk av telefonkatalogen</button>
    </form>

In which case it downloads as you would expect.

Comment: in that case you can try submitting the form to a hidden iframe, see what happens... i am not sure but i think that the hidden iframe will promote for download

Comment: I ended up using a javascript lib called fileDownload.js ( http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/ ) Which does exactly that, with a cookie for determining when the request is finished.