# Can you download an image that's already been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple image loaded from the server:

```
<img src="mycoolimage.jpg" />
```

The image is already being shown in the browser. Is there any way using JavaScript to get the image to save to my file system without actually having to send another request to the server?

Comment: **No.** You cannot access the filesystem with JavaScript. Sorry. `#SecurityIssues`

Comment: Or, may be, are you trying to do something like this: [Creating download prompt using purely javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548102/creating-download-prompt-using-purely-javascript)

Comment: @PraveenKumar can be done using api's like canvas and saveAs

Comment: @charlietfl Well how about adding that as an answer to one of the many "create a download prompt in javascript" questions we have floating around and close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @charlietfl This looks like direct access to the file system by JavaScript. Right? Not triggering a saveAs.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I only see OP asking if it can be done without another request....which it can. Not automatically of course but that wasn't part of the question

Comment: @charlietfl My mistake. But what is `Is there any way using JavaScript to get the image to save to my file system`.

Comment: Automatically ..no. Manually ..yes

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can! But not on all browser ;) (

Have a look of the HTML5 doc for downloading client side [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

```
<a href="yourImg" download>Download</a>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csreya20/)

Hope its help ;)

Comment: Nopes. Direct download is what the OP is expecting I guess?