# safari upload csv file open a plain text in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a solution to download a csv file in safari, 
I have in the link data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8 ....etc
what's happen is in safari it open a plain textcsv in the browser
NB: everything is ok on chrome and IE

Do you have any Ideas..
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [Javascript - Download CSV as File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177078/javascript-download-csv-as-file) and changed it a little bit to make it work with jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function downloadFile2(fileName, urlData){
      $('#dlink').attr('download',fileName);
      $('#dlink').attr('href',urlData);
      $('#dlink')[0].click();
  }

  var data = '"Column One","Column Two","Column Three"';
  downloadFile2('2.csv','data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="dlink" href="" style="display:none"></a>
```