# How to write a value that contains a comma to a csv file?

Tags: javascript, csv, escaping

I have a javascript program to write values to a csv file.
I have a value that includes comma within.
How to do this?
I am newbie to javascript.
can you please help me?

I tried double quotes

```
content += record.number +","+ record.category +","+ record.status +","+ record.approval_status +","+ record.requested_by +","+ record.assigned_to +","+record.assign_dept +","+ record.coordinator +","+ record.coord_phone +","+ record.planned_start +","+ record.planned_end +","+record.reason +","+ record.risk_assessment +","+ record.logical_name +","+ "record.assets" +","+ record.request_date +","+ record.subcategory +","+ record.priority_code +","+ record.impact +","+  record.sched_outage_start +","+ record.sched_outage_end  + "\n";
```

record.assets is the field that will have comma within.

Comment: Just quote delimit your columns in your CSV output.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836273/export-javascript-data-to-csv-file-without-server-interaction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close them in quotes and escape double quotes?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""",4900.00

in your case:

```
"," + "record.assets" + ","
```

should be

```
"," + '"' + record.assets.replace(/"/g,'""') + '"' + ","
```

Comment: I tried this... But still it wrote in separate fields together with "

Comment: What were you reading it with?  Did you tell the program that you had quote delimited data?

Comment: Actually there is product, in which the mentioned javascript program acts as a trigger, when an update is made in the system it writes to a csv file.

Comment: The value of the field will be like --> [C++ object Datum] - {"CAR11BANBAN021129", "CAR11BANMYS021149"}

Answer (score 0):

You can put your text between quotes. 
You are not obliged to use a comma , you can use a ";" too (dutch/german format but works well)
--> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values 
    1997;Ford;E350;2,34

Comment: I dont have control on that field, which has a comma within

Comment: you can use an ascii char and make an str replace after.
ie : 1997,Ford,E350,"Super% luxurious truck"
and make a str_replace(yourString,"%",",")

It's working with all other chars (in case of you'll need to pass % in your data)

Comment: Thanks Azrael_404. It worked. I replaced comma with semicolon & inserted to csv