# Adding Formula from JavaScript to CSV to be imported to Google Sheet results in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been trying to add a formula shown below to a single column in Google sheets using JavaScript, but it is resulting in different columns, due to the comma.

`=IF(A2="VALID", B2, 0)`

Currently, the code I am using to generate the CSV is below:

```
var CSVRowDemo = [];
var CSVDemo = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,';
CSVRowDemo.push(['VALID/INVALID', 'Value', 'Check'])
let index = 2;
let check = '"' + '=IF(A'+index+'=\"VALID\"", B'+index+', 0)'.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
CSVRowDemo.push(['VALID', '100', check])
CSVRowDemo.forEach(function(rowArray) {
    let row = rowArray.join(',');
    CSVDemo += row + '\r\n';
});

encodedUri = encodeURI(CSVDemo);
link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "Basic.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

Expected to see it like this. (This is how it is rendered in LibreOffice Calc.)
[image: Expected to see it like this.]

Rather saw it like this in Google Sheets.
[image: Rather saw it like this.]

The closest, which comes to answer this is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144184/how-to-write-a-value-that-contains-a-comma-to-a-csv-file/22144225#22144225).

I am trying to use only Javascript instead of NodeJS or other libraries.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure about the method for putting the created CSV data to Google Spreadsheet, can you test the the following modification?

#### From:

```
let check = '"' + '=IF(A'+index+'=\"VALID\"", B'+index+', 0)'.replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
```

#### To:

```
let check = `"=IF(A${index}=""VALID"", B${index}, 0)"`;
```

or

```
let check = '"=IF(A'+index+'=""VALID"", B'+index+', 0)"';
```

- In my environment, I could confirm that the CSV data with the following modification can be imported to the Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: The first one worked for me. Thank You for the help!

Comment: @remedcu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.