# Javascript: Exporting large text/csv file crashes Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, csv, export

I have the following Javascript code to export CSV file on the client side. However Google Chrome crashes every time I try to export a large array. What is the limit of the data string allowed in Chrome? Is it possible that it is hitting the memory limit allowed in Chrome? If the data string is too long for Chrome, how will I go about exporting large CSV files on the client side?

```
var csvRows = [...]; //Array with 40000 items, each item is 100 characters long.

var csvString = csvRows.join("\r\n");

var a = document.createElement('a');

a.href        = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target      = '_blank';
a.download    = 'export.csv';

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

(Expected file size is about 6.4MB)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

had the same Problem and solved it using [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob).

For example:

```
csvData = new Blob([csvString], { type: 'text/csv' }); 
var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(csvData);
a.href =  csvUrl;
```

Source: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24611096/3048937

Comment: I have a similar problem, which is to write .xlsx file data created by excelbuilder.js's `EB.createFile()` function. When it has 8000+ records in the table, the browser crashes. I am trying to save it as a blob. However, what is written in file turns out to be the base64 string rather than the excel file data. I've tried different type strings. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I also have no idea why this works. I was using `encodeURI` function before.

Answer (score 13):

I used following function to download CSV. Worked for me in IE/Firefox/Chrome

```
function downloadFile(data, fileName) {
        var csvData = data;
        var blob = new Blob([ csvData ], {
            type : "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
        });

        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
            // FOR IE BROWSER
            navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
            // FOR OTHER BROWSERS
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            var csvUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.href = csvUrl;
            link.style = "visibility:hidden";
            link.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this compatible with Safari? @Ganesh

Comment: Have not tested this with Safari.

Comment: For those that stumble across this, I tested this solution in all modern browsers (NOT IE, but edge) and it worked perfectly.