# JS export string as csv being cut down

Tags: javascript, string, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a valid csv on a JS client application. I have a function that converts arrays to a csv string by adding commas between each item and a line terminator between each row of arrays. I am positive that my function works well (atleast with formatting). However when it's given more than 160 rows, it just stops appending. What might be wrong? Is there a limit to how long a string can be? A limit to how long a csv generated client side can be?

My CSV header is: `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,`

[Edit] I think it actually is some sort of a limit that the browser set. Not sure if it's with how long a CSV file can be, or how long a string can be. Any idea how I can get around this limitation?

[Edit] Code:

```
const BASE_CSV_HEADER = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8'

const stringify = text => {
    let retval
    try {
        retval = text.toString()
    } catch(e) {
        retval = text
    }

    return typeof retval === 'string' ? retval || ' '
}

const stripForCSV = (row) => {
    let newRow = []
    row.forEach((text) => {
        text = stringify(text)
        newRow.push(text.replace(/,/g, '.'))  // to avoid comma clashes
    })
    return newRow
}

const arraysToCsv = (arrays) => {
    let csv = ''
    arrays.forEach(row => {
        row = stripForCSV(row)
        csv += row.join(',');
        csv += "\n";
    })
    return csv
}

const getCSV (jsObject) => {
    const arrays = convertJsObjectToArrayOfArrays(jsObject)
    const csv = arraysToCsv(arrays)
    return BASE_CSV_HEADER + csv  // Removed encodeURI
}
```

[EDIT]

Solved!!

As mentioned here: [Export HTML table to csv in google chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610694/export-html-table-to-csv-in-google-chrome-browser/24611096#24611096)

I had to change the download type to Blob.

Comment: Please share the code you are using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610694/export-html-table-to-csv-in-google-chrome-browser/24611096#24611096

Comment: @abhinavxeon Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you!!