# Is there a good cross-browser way to export tables as CSVs with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, csv, download

I implemented a table-to-CSV download by changing an a link's `href="download.csv"` and `download="data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,......"`

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari, for some reason. I've not checked IE yet.

Any idea what I should do to make it work cross browser?

Comment: Shouldn’t the contents of `href` and `download` be the other way round?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export JavaScript array info to csv (on client side)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964035/how-to-export-javascript-array-info-to-csv-on-client-side)

Comment: Yep, [doesn’t seem to be supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download)…

Comment: For IE, Firefox, Chrome, see answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836273/export-javascript-data-to-csv-file-without-server-interaction and/or my library at https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv;  there is a QUnit test file if someone wants to test this on Safari.