# Download a URL as a Text File

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script

```
<a name="pack,1,SER_260,NZ vs SL Series,,,yes,PITEM_233,PDATA_234,no" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playLink(this);" style="text-decoration:none;">NZ vs SL Series</a>
```

In this moment when I click on this link it opened rtmp link like this

```
rtsp://10.62.230.21:554/livefeed/SLVSNZ_QVGA.sdp?msd=94775447908&pi=&pd=&sn=NZvsSLSeries&b=3G&os=WAP&cn=&m=GT-I9505&mcc=&mnc=&v=1.14&lac=&cid=&op=Dialog&st=1&sid=&pid=@00INY0091&stamp=3659098938&sign=a308650741b841c2add44629c15d0ec1
```

The thing I want to do is not open the link the thing that I want to do is save this URL as a text File or m3u File.Please help me guys.I would be happy to have a example here because I'm not a genius in this field and Any other idea and solutions will be accepted.The only thing that I want to do is saving or showing the URL not opening .Thank You.

Comment: [How to download data as a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836273/export-javascript-data-to-csv-file-without-server-interaction)

Comment: The link seems to work fine for me, redirects to a question here on SO, did you click on it with your computer mouse ?

Comment: yes I asked this question after checked that solution that you mentioned above It's still open the url with a media player