# Create an excel file with a few styles using client side JavaScript (if possible using js-xlsx library)

Tags: javascript, excel, cordova, js-xlsx

I want to create an excel file(in ***.xlsx*** format) and make it available for download using **Client Side JavaScript**. I was able to create a sample file using **[js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)** library. But I am not able to apply any styles to it. At least some basic styles including ***background color*** to header, ***bold font*** for header and ***text wrapping*** for the cells are required.

**js-xlsx** library documentation says that we can give styles using [Cell Object](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style#cell-object).

I tried giving styles using the cell object but it is not reflecting in the downloaded .xlsx file. I even tried reading a .xlsx file and writing the same file back using **XLSX.write()** function. But it gives back an excel file with no styles at all. *Ideally I expect the downloaded file to have the same styles of uploaded file.* No font color or background colors were applied in the recreated file. I use ***Excel 2013*** for testing the downloaded files.

Please find below the excel screenshots before and after uploading.

**Original File**

[image]

**Downloaded File**

[image]

The code is given below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<script type="text/javascript" src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Blob.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>

<script>

function s2ab(s) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;
}   

/* set up XMLHttpRequest */
var url = "template-sample.xlsx";
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", url, true);
oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

oReq.onload = function(e) {
  var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

  /* convert data to binary string */
  var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
  var arr = new Array();
  for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  var bstr = arr.join("");

  /* Call XLSX */
  var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary", cellStyles:true});

    console.log("read workbook");
    console.log(workbook);
  /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    var wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary', cellStyles: true});
    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "template-download.xlsx");

}

function read(){
    oReq.send();    
}


</script>


</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="read()">save xlsx</button>
</body></html>
```

Sample code was taken from [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks).

What I look forward is either an option to give styles to cells using **js-xlsx** library or another library which provides this functionality. I found a library named [exceljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) , but it requires ***node js*** to support it. I am looking for a purely client side based solution. This is to be used for a ***Cordova*** based tablet and desktop application.

Comment: For downloading excel file without using any library [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552921/5511982)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

After some research I was able to find the solution to my own question.
I found a new library named [xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style) for giving styles. **xlsx-style** is build on top of **js-xlsx** for giving styles also to the generated excel file. The styles can be given to the cells using a new attribute inside cell object.

The explanation is available at the npm [xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style#cell-styles) page.

Styling is given using a style object associated with each cell. Font, Color, alignment etc can be given using this style object.

I have added a minimalist demo in a [github page](https://nithinbaby.github.io/js-xlsx-style/).
The sample code is available at this [github repository](https://github.com/nithinbaby/js-xlsx-style).

You can find the screenshot of the generated excel page below.
[image]

Comment: i was looking for the same solution.could you please update with the sample code how you did it using `xlsx-style`.My requirement is that write data into a .xlsx file with some basic style. Appreciate any help.

Comment: can you please let me know how style object is defined in cell object.I tried this way but doesnt work.`var cell = {v: data[R][C],s:{bgColor:"#E1697B"}};`

Comment: i was able to get it worked.but its better if you could post your working code snippets here because there is lack of examples.Then it will help for   some one.thanks.

Comment: @gihan I've added a sample in my github respository. Anyone is welcome to make it better.

Comment: @Nitin Baby I have to create similar excel-sheet in ionic. Any idea how it will work for ionic. I tried but no luck.

Comment: Great! So helpful!

Comment: Thanks @DarlanDieterich. Your upvotes are my inspiration. I'm very glad that this post was useful for many. I had to try a lot before I was able to find that such a solution existed. But now I'm happy.

Comment: @NithinBaby the future is shared knowledge! Thanks Dude!

Answer (score 4):

As another alternative for writing simple `*.xlsx` files I'd propose `write-excel-file` package.

https://npmjs.com/package/write-excel-file

It supports styling cells with bold font, text color, background color, horizontal alignment, vertical alignment and text wrapping on overflow.

```js
import writeXlsxFile from 'write-excel-file'

const data = [
  [{
    value: 'Row 1, Col 1',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }, {
    value: 'Row 1, Col 2',
    color: '#ffffff',
    backgroundColor: '#cc0000'
  }],
  [{
    value: 'Row 2, Col 1',
    align: 'right',
    alignVertical: 'top'
  }, {
    value: 'Row 2, Col 2. Long Text \n Multi-line',
    wrap: true
  }]
]

await writeXlsxFile(data, {
  fileName: 'file.xlsx'
})
```

Comment: As `xlsx-style` didn´t have the possibility to put width on a column and `xlsx` had no styling at all, `write-excel-file` was the perfect solution for me. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I am using this write-excel-file, but unable to add image into the cell. Can anybody please suggest how to add image? I couldn't find any documentation on its official site.

Comment: I've researched a bit the topic of inserting images in a spreadsheet and described the implementation notes in the document: https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/write-excel-file/-/blob/main/docs/IMAGES.md?ref_type=heads

Currently, I don't think that I'd be implementing it. But if anyone would like to, the document contains the instructions.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a couple of examples for using [xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style) which I didn't really find clear or all that helpful to get what I needed fast.

Here is my solution using xlsx-style with the barebones needed to create a workbook, set a cell value, and color that cell.

I struggled a little bit with getting the right xlsx.core.min.js file, for some reason not all versions have this included. I ended up copying directly from Nithin Baby (the anwsers demo)

Heres the simple version of the code

```
/* Object for the excel workbook data */
class Workbook {
    constructor() {
        this.SheetNames = [];
        this.Sheets = {};
    }
}

/* function for downloading the excel file */
function s2ab(s) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0; i != s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;
}

// create the worksheet data
var ws_data = {}
var range = { s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 10, r: 10 } }; // worksheet cell range 
ws_data['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range); // set cell the range

var cell = { // create cell
    v: 'test', // value
    s: { // style
        fill: {
            fgColor: { rgb: "FF6666" } // red
        }
    }
}
ws_data[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: 1, r: 1 })] = cell; // add the cell to the sheet data

// create workbook and download
var wb = new Workbook();
wb.SheetNames.push('test'); // create new worksheet
wb.Sheets['test'] = ws_data; // set workseet data to the cell data
var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary' }); //workbook output
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }), "Test Color.xlsx") // save workbook
```

Couple things to note.

`XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: 1, r: 1 })` is their way of assigning excel cords to numbers.
for example: `{ c: 1, r: 1 } == 'B2'`

If you can get the excel file to download but the cell data doesn't show up it most likely has to do with the sheets range value. Make sure it matches or is bigger than the amount of data.
`range = { s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 10, r: 10 } };` where 's' = current and 'e' = total from what i've gathered.

[xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style) has more attributes that can be set when creating the cell its worth a quick skim to know what's there. Now its up to you to figure out how you want to create/style the cells you need for your output and set to the range value appropriately.

Comment: The default xlsx.core.min.js file was the reason why the styles didn't get applied correctly for me either. I ended up copying Nithin's copy and it worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xlsx-style](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style), foreach yout collection 'WorkSheet' and add the style before add in 'WorkBook'. The property responsible for this process is the 's' (style).

Sample:

```
_.forEach(ws, (v, c) => {
    if (c !== '!ref') {
        if (header.indexOf(v.v) >= 0) {
            ws[c]['s'] = {
                fill: {
                patternType: 'solid', // none / solid
                fgColor: {rgb: 'FFD3D3D3'}
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```