# How can I add title and blank rows before table while exporting to excel from angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angular, excel, typescript, styles

I want to export data from table into excel file, but I want to add title and few blank rows before table. Also I want to do some css for that table.

This is my code in .ts file and it works but I want to style it a little bit.  I didn't find anything for my problem, but also I'm beginner in this :)

```
 exportExcel() : void {
   const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet =XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.excelArray);
   
    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');
    
    /* save to file */  
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

That package is well documented: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx#writing-functions however they don't have any styling functionality.

Someone has forked the package to add styling: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx-style, via the `s` property of a `Cell Object`

Answer taken from here: [Create an excel file with a few styles using client side JavaScript (if possible using js-xlsx library)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40486860/12914833)