# ExtJS/JavaScript - how to post list of grid records to download url?

Tags: javascript, download

i need to pass a record or list of records as a post param to a download action... is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A seemingly straight forward question with a complex answer. MDN has written it up better than I could ever do:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

For a ExtJS approach you could create a form without rendering it:

```
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    url: 'https://www.sencha.com/img/learn/ExtDesignerGettingStarted_html_m4fab468.png',
    standardSubmit:true,
    baseParams: {
        param1: 'textfield',
        param2: 123
    }
});
formPanel.form.submit();
delete formPanel;
```

This creates a POST with params like this:
[image: chrome network tab]

Note that your header will have to respond with specific headers to trigger the download in the browser, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3358583/1861459

Comment: yes i want to use an ExtJS approach but as far as i know an AJAX req cant be used to download a file... I normally use a hidden iframe and pass the params into the query string but in this case it needs to be POST

Comment: Try programmatically creating a Ext form with standardSubmit (unfortunately you have to have a Panel too it seems). Updated the answer with this approach.

Comment: thanks, just ended up using the hidden form approach. Was hoping there would be something similar for grids but for now this seems to be the best solutions.